# Flutter 2.0 outlined button height to fit on the table cell

Tags: flutter, button, flutter-layout

I'm currently working on flutter 2.0.3.

And, I have a problem with layout handling using buttons.

I wanted to implement a table of buttons.

```dart
Widget createButton(String label) {
  return OutlinedButton(
    child: Text(label, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
    onPressed: () => null,
  );
}

Widget buttonSection = Table(
  border: TableBorder.all(color: Colors.black),
  children: [
    TableRow(children: [
      createButton('button 1'),
      createButton('button 2'),
      createButton('button 3'),
      createButton('button 4'),
    ]),
    TableRow(children: [
      createButton('button 5'),
      createButton('button 6'),
      createButton('button 7'),
      createButton('button 8'),
    ])
  ],
);
```

I implemented flutter code like this and put them into ListView.

However, I found that **OutlinedButton** does not fully occupy the cell region.

[image: Result of flutter code]

How can I extend the height of buttons to fill cells without margin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because by default the button has padding... To remove

```
OutlinedButton(
        style: ButtonStyle(
             tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                ),
...
)
```